# Android/Kotlin - local BroadcastReceiver is never activated by DownloadManager

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I'm trying to detect when a DownloadManager download is completed. Unfortunately, the local BroadcastReceiver I'm trying to use for that never gets called. I have seen multiple similar questions, but none solved my problem; also, if the BroadcastReceiver isn't local but declared in the manifest it DOES get called, so I don't think it's an issue with the DownloadManager.

I can't use an external BroadcastReceiver because I need to update the UI (more specifically, open another activity) when the download is completed, and as far as I know that can't be done from an external receiver (please correct me if I'm wrong there).

The DownloadManager call:

```
private fun download() {
    val mobileNetSSDConfigRequest: DownloadManager.Request = DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse("https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/gotcha-weights/weights/MobileNetSSD/MobileNetSSD.prototxt")
    )
    mobileNetSSDConfigRequest.setDescription("Downloading MobileNetSSD configuration")
    mobileNetSSDConfigRequest.setTitle("MobileNetSSD configuration")

    mobileNetSSDConfigRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            "Android/data/giorgioghisotti.unipr.it.gotcha/files/weights/", "MobileNetSSD.prototxt")

    val manager: DownloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    manager.enqueue(mobileNetSSDConfigRequest)
}
```

which is called upon being granted permissions:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when (requestCode) {
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.isEmpty()
                    || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || grantResults[2] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || grantResults[3] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || grantResults[4] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Sorry, this app requires camera and storage access to work!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()
            } else {
                val mobileSSDConfig = File(sDir + mobileNetSSDConfigPath)
                if (!mobileSSDConfig.exists()) download()
                else {
                    val myIntent = Intent(this, MainMenu::class.java)
                    this.startActivity(myIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The BroadcastIntent is declared like so (Splash is the name of the activity):

```
private val broadcastReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.action) {
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE -> {
                val myIntent = Intent(this@Splash, MainMenu::class.java)
                this@Splash.startActivity(myIntent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and is registered in the activity's onCreate() method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)
    )

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

I tried registering the receiver in the onResume method and declaring it inside the onCreate method, no change. As far as I can tell, I'm doing this exactly as I saw it done in a few accepted answers and I can't see the problem. I know for a fact that the BroadcastReceiver is never called, I checked through debugging and with all sorts of console logs. The DownloadManager seems to work as intended since the file is correctly downloaded and external services are called correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and turned out that calling simply `registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)`, without getting an instance of the `LocalBroadcastManager` solved the problem.

So possibly the issue was that the receiver was being registered on the wrong context object.
[remember also to take care of the un-registration of the receiver]

I did my like this

```
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
}

public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: I gave up and used a dedicated class file even though it's a bit more complex - I'll try your solution when I have some time, but I ran my code through the debugger and the broadcast receiver was *never called*, which (as far as I know) shouldn't be the case if it were just a context issue.